# Cloud Object Storage Account add Another Cloud's Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, object-storage

Can one cloud's object storage user account able to add another s3 service provider's bucket, just like adding bucket of another account from the same cloud?

I have a app need to access raw data in one cloud's S3 and meta data in another cloud's S3. But the app can only connect with 1 access key & secret and there is limitation that the meta data cannot move to the S3 where the raw data are. I am studying whether I can add the meta data's bucket to raw data's S3 like they are in the same cloud service provider.

I tried to use the function like add bucket (I am using Huawei OceanStor as Object Storage), but that only support adding bucket within Huawei OceanStor itself.

Comment: No. Credentials provided by one "cloud provider" are not compatible with another cloud provider's service. They are competitors and have no reason to interoperate.

Comment: The generic term you are looking for is "object store", not "S3". S3 is specifically AWS's object store.